# Opposite if statement in php

Tags: php, if-statement

i'm new at php and i'm practicing with the basics of php

now i want to know what the opposite is of == when using the if statement.

I hope someone can help

Thanks.

Comment: It's `!=`. Look at the [comparison operators table from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp), or [look up the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). [Searching php not equal](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+not+equal) is also an easy way to get the answer.

Comment: You want to know the opposite of "equal to"... wouldn't a quick search for "PHP not equal to" have been much quicker than asking a question here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `!=` is that all you wanted to ask?

Research a little, before you ask a question. Trust me, it won't hurt. You will feel joy when you find out the facts by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The operator for "not equal to" in PHP is !=

I might also suggest you check out PHP.net. They have a ton of useful information on the language: http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Answer (score 1):

`!=` - not equal

`<>` - different

Answer (score 1):

The exact opposite is !== or != (see [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) article for difference).

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php the answer you are probably looking for is $a != $b , be sure to check out the operaters syntax in the php manual to learn more about what you can do.